# Rails 3.2, javascript executing twice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a brand new rails app that has the following code:

## application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

## thing.js *(lives in same path as application.js)*

```
alert("This is running");
```

## index.html

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

When I navigate to the page, I see the alert twice. Anyone know why? I have no pre-compiled assets.

Comment: Oh my god. I just spent HOURS pulling my hair out over this. Turned out that when I upgraded to rails 4, it added `= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true` in addition to my original `= javascript_include_tag "application"`. Deleting my original and keeping the new turbolinks one saved the day.

Answer (score 4):

the application layout already includes the `application.js` file, so this arises because the `application.js` is getting included twice.